# OOP - Understanding Inheritance

Tags: python, class, object, oop, inheritance

I'm beginning my journey into OOP by trying to learn inheritance. I saw this code in an online quiz about the topic and I was hoping someone could explain it to me since it makes little sense to me.

```
class A(object) :

    def __init__(self, x) :
        self._x = 2 * x
    def m1(self, x) :
        return self.m2(x) + 2
    def m2(self, x) :
        return x - 1
    
class B(A) :

    def m2(self, y) :
        self._y = y
        return self._x + self._y
```

For the following, if I was to say a = A(1), what would be the expected return? The initialization multiplies the 1 with 2, so now the instance of x has value 2. What happens with the method m1? it receives this instance of X but in the return it refers to m2? so is that x=2 passed into m2 first and then the return of 1 is passed to m1? which adds 2 to it?

As for Class B, I see it changes the inherited m2 method from Class A, but the x value that is added to the y, is that an inherited x value from Class A?

Sorry about the endless questions but I'm just beginning and it seems hard to wrap my head around.

Comment: Here is the question and additional statements I was expected to apply.
a = A(1)
b = B(2)
c = C(1, 1)
d = D(2, 1)

What does a.m1(2) return?

Comment: What are `C` and `D`?

Comment: By taking x as 2 in m1, it leads to answer 3 which is correct. But I'm wondering what relation a=A(1) as stated before the question has to do with it?

Comment: @Codeman I could add them if necessary but I felt understanding the first step would allow me to complete the rest on my own, which would be true learning I believe.

Comment: Very well. Could you elaborate on 'expected return'? Are you talking about m1 or m2?

Comment: More correctly, the instance `a` has an attribute `_x` that has the value 2.

Comment: There's little point (in this example) of setting `self._y`, as it's not used by any other method of `B`. (Indeed, there *are* no other methods of `B` to use it.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to figure out what the code does is to run it.

```
>>> a = A(1)
>>> a.m1(10)
11
```

An important thing to note here (which from your question it sounded like you might be confused on) is that the value of `x` you pass to `A.__init__` does **not** get used by `A.m1`!  So `A.m1(x)` just returns `x + 1` no matter how you initialized the `A` instance.

```
>>> a = A(1000)
>>> a.m1(1)
2
>>> a.m1(10)
11
>>> a.m1(100)
101
```

Okay, what if we make a `B` the same way?

```
>>> b = B(1)
>>> b.m1(10)
14
```

Now it's different, because `B.m2` is different from `A.m2`.  We can just run those on their own to see:

```
>>> a.m2(10)
9
>>> b.m2(10)
12
```

`a.m2(10)` is 9 because `a.m2(x)` is *always* just `x - 1` regardless of what `a._x` is.

But `b.m2(10)` returns `b._x + 10`, which in this case is 12 -- and so `b.m1(10)` returns that plus 2.  The results will be different if we change what `b._x` is by initializing our `B` with a different value:

```
>>> b = B(2)
>>> b.m2(10)
14
>>> b.m1(10)
16
```

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. I'll go attempt the rest now!

Comment: What is the y value that is introduced in m2 of class B? and how come a.m2(x) is independent of a._x where as b.m2 is dependent?

**Edit:** I understand how it is dependent since it adds the self._x to self._y, so it utilizes the initial x instance with the new instance of y right?

Comment: @AgentiDiogenes The y value is not dependant on what you pass in the function, but `B(x).m2(y)` is NOT only dependant on the `y` since you use the `self._x` from `super().__init()`.

For `A`, you do not use `self._x`, so m1/m2 is called as `A(x).m1(y)` and is only dependant on the `y`.

Comment: I'll note that setting an instance attribute in a random method is bad practice and makes understanding inheritance unnecessarily confusing -- if this code is part of an online course it raises doubts for me about how good the course is.

Answer (score 0):

You can always track what happens:

```py
 ...
class B(A) :

    def m2(self, y) :
        self._y = y
        return self._x + self._y
```

`class B` then looks like `Bx` as `m2` is overridden:

```
class Bx:

    def __init__(self, x) :
        self._x = 2 * x
    def m1(self, x) :
        return self.m2(x) + 2
    def m2(self, y) :
        self._y = y
        return self._x + self._y
```

So this is how `class B` looks like-ish when it has inherited A

Comment: Ah so that's how it really looks after inheriting the methods from A. Makes sense ,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try answering your questions in order:

1. If you were to say `a = A(1)`, `__init__` would set variable self._x to `2`. **This does not change, as you do not ever edit the** `self._x` **variable after this.**

   - The functions `m1` and `m2` could return anything based on `x` that you pass in. Did you mean `self._x`? And yes, `m2` would execute when you call `m1`, `m1` for any number `x` would just return `x + 1`.
2. `a = A(1)` is just instantiating class `A`, the methods would work with just `A(x).m1(y)`, whereas if you include `a = A(1)` you would execute `a.m1(y)`.
3. Instantiating class `B` with any number (`B(x)`) runs the `__init__()` function of `A` (`super().init(args)`) with the `x` passed (Try running it yourself with something like `b = B(2); print(b._x)`!). Thus, `self._x` is `2 * x` that you passed for B!
4. You have overwritten method `m2()` in class `B`, so `m2()` from `A` is not used in `B`.

If you have any other questions comment and I'll attempt to answer them!